# INNO: Disallow "Ignore" when file is in use

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup for the installer for my windows application. If a user has the application when the installer is run (eg. for an update), the installer will stop when it is unable to replace a file in use, and it allows the user to select whether to Abort, Ignore, or Retry.

I would like it to only allow Abort or Retry and remove the option to Ignore. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Or if this can't be done, how can I make the installer abort if the application is running?

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to detect whether the application is running requires co-operation from the application, so it's best to work this out *before* you ship your first version. **Use Inno Setup's `AppMutex` setting.** There is an [example in the Inno Setup knowledge base](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?mutexsessions) for setting up a mutex visible in multiple sessions. There is more about `AppMutex` in Inno Setup's help file.